# Improve Bar Plot and Line Plot Aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to improve the aesthetics of my code output:

- add dots to both lines then have the subsequent percentage value above each dot (app_1 and app_2)
- have the value associated with each blue bar in the middle of the bar (Total_Wth)

I tried geom_point but it removed my right hand side Y axis and added in a second key.

```
x <- c("Mar_22", "Apr_22", "May_22", "June_22", "July_22", "Aug_22")
Total_Wth <- c(88959, 100396, 117989, 130561, 150282, 148970)
App_1 <- c(0.91, 0.9, 0.91, 0.88, 0.9, 0.9)
App_2 <- c(0.09, 0.1, 0.09, 0.12, 0.10, 0.10)

df <- data.frame(x, Total_Wth, App_1, App_2)
transf_fact <- max(df$Total_Wth)/max(df$App_1)
head(df)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("App")), ~.*transf_fact) %>%
  gather(y_var, val, -x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(x, df$x), y = val, fill = y_var)) +
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter(y_var == "Total_Wth")) +
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(y_var != "Total_Wth"),
            aes(color = y_var, group = y_var),
            size = 1.2) +
  scale_fill_discrete(aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / transf_fact, 
                                         name = "%", 
                                         labels = scales::percent),
                     limits = c(0, 170000), 
                     breaks = c(34000 * 0:5)) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Total",
       title = "Example Heading",
       subtitle = "Example subheading") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
        legend.text = element_text(size=7),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size=8, hjust=0, face="italic", color="black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```r
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("App")), ~.*transf_fact) %>%
  gather(y_var, val, -x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(x, df$x), y = val, fill = y_var)) +
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter(y_var == "Total_Wth")) +
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(y_var != "Total_Wth"),
            aes(color = y_var, group = y_var), size = 1.2) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(y_var != "Total_Wth")) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(y_var != "Total_Wth"),
            aes(label = scales::percent(val / transf_fact, 0.1)), nudge_y = 5e3) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(y_var == "Total_Wth"),
            aes(label = val), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / transf_fact, 
                                         name = "%", 
                                         labels = scales::percent),
                     limits = c(0, 170000), 
                     breaks = c(34000 * 0:5)) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Total",
       title = "Example Heading",
       subtitle = "Example subheading") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = NA))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
        legend.text = element_text(size=7),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size=8, hjust=0, face=3, color="black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"))
```

[image]